# Ping Interconnected PCs End-To-End

Tags: networking, ip, ping, interface, crossover

I have the following network topology:

```
[PC 1] - - - [PC 2] - - - [PC 3] - - - [PC 4]
```

Each machine is connected via a crossover cable. I can ping from PC 1 to PC 2, but how can I configure things so as to ping from PC 1 all the way to PC 4?

Comment: How do you have the interfaces set up?   Does PC1 have IP knowledge of PC4? What OS?  Why not a switch?

Comment: Are the PC's bridging or routing? Are you trying to create one IP network or 3?

Answer (score 0):

With one nic card on each host only way you can do this is to have one computer in the middle and transfer data from one to another to another. You cant get the other two computers to see more than itself and one more computer. Otherwise you need some basic network medium like hub repeating arp requests to all the ports where hosts will be interconnected. Plus I am quite positive on modern nic cards you do not need to use crossover cables anymore.